# Sidebar pushes to bottom of page on IE using WP

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer

I have this situation in IE wherein the sidebar pushes to the bottom of the page whilst using IE. If I click on the "Compatability View" button in IE it fixes but I can't seem to find the solution to the problem.

Example can be seen here: http://www.gardensupplyinc.com/wordpress/products/shepherds-hooks/

Unfortunately I picked up on this project at it's completion and the theme was created by someone else.

Comment: I have voted to close this question because it's too specific to your site, and unlikely to help any future visitors.  The best questions have a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code *directly* into the question. Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
.inpage #secondary { width:225px; }
```

to

```
.inpage #secondary { width:220px; }
```